# Sql transorm date of type 26FEB2018

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to import a txt file to my database.

One of the columns represent a date in the format of 26FEB2018.

Is there a way to quickly transform this value into a date format (yyyy-mm-dd) either with the import wizard or with a chunk of code after importing the file

If you need any other information please ask.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: If the language is set to American or British, the SQL server would understand that as a date. Otherwise set language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `cast()` after importing the file:

```
select cast(dt as date)
```

Comment: I didn t know that can be "cast" can recognise this format. Thanks